Gazebo install osx 15.0.1 M1 fails
First time posting here.  I hope i have this in the right place.
I need some help ...
I am trying to install Gazebo on my M1 mac mini.  I am running osx 15.0.1 (sequoia)
I am following :
https://medium.com/@shubhjain_007/installing-ros2-humble-gazebo-on-mac-m1-m2-m3-silicon-853e0737dcc8#:~:text=If%20you're%20excited%20about,it%20as%20simple%20as%20possible
and a more in depth video version:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GEgVpdZj3tY
i can get conda (ros2) and Rviz running -- but every time I try to install Gazebo it fails.
i am running this command:
curl -ssL http://get.gazebosim.org | sh
the error / warnings in terminal follow:

Installing gazebo11 from osrf/simulation
==> Installing dependencies for osrf/simulation/gazebo11: osrf/simulation/ignition-math6, ossp-uuid, osrf/simulation/ignition-common3, osrf/simulation/ignition-tools, abseil, protobuf, osrf/simulation/ignition-msgs5, jsoncpp, libzip, osrf/simulation/ignition-fuel-tools4, cppzmq, osrf/simulation/ignition-transport8, libtar, libzzip, hwloc, tbb, osrf/simulation/ogre1.9, md4c, qt@5, qwt-qt5, osrf/simulation/tinyxml1, osrf/simulation/sdformat9 and osrf/simulation/simbody
==> Installing osrf/simulation/gazebo11 dependency: osrf/simulation/ignitio
==> cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH=@loader_path/../lib
==> make install
Last 15 lines from /Users/stevedaniels/Library/Logs/Homebrew/ignition-math6/02.make:
         To avoid this warning please remove this line from your configuration file or upgrade it using "doxygen -u"
warning: Tag 'RTF_SOURCE_CODE' at line 1941 of file '/tmp/ignition-math6-20241013-16267-1wccck/ignition-math-6.15.1/build/api.dox' has become obsolete.
         To avoid this warning please remove this line from your configuration file or upgrade it using "doxygen -u"
warning: Tag 'DOCBOOK_PROGRAMLISTING' at line 2046 of file '/tmp/ignition-math6-20241013-16267-1wccck/ignition-math-6.15.1/build/api.dox' has become obsolete.
         To avoid this warning please remove this line from your configuration file or upgrade it using "doxygen -u"
warning: Tag 'CLASS_DIAGRAMS' at line 2234 of file '/tmp/ignition-math6-20241013-16267-1wccck/ignition-math-6.15.1/build/api.dox' has become obsolete.
         To avoid this warning please remove this line from your configuration file or upgrade it using "doxygen -u"
warning: Tag 'DOT_FONTNAME' at line 2276 of file '/tmp/ignition-math6-20241013-16267-1wccck/ignition-math-6.15.1/build/api.dox' has become obsolete.
         To avoid this warning please remove this line from your configuration file or upgrade it using "doxygen -u"
warning: Tag 'DOT_FONTSIZE' at line 2283 of file '/tmp/ignition-math6-20241013-16267-1wccck/ignition-math-6.15.1/build/api.dox' has become obsolete.
         To avoid this warning please remove this line from your configuration file or upgrade it using "doxygen -u"
warning: Tag 'DOT_TRANSPARENT' at line 2509 of file '/tmp/ignition-math6-20241013-16267-1wccck/ignition-math-6.15.1/build/api.dox' has become obsolete.
         To avoid this warning please remove this line from your configuration file or upgrade it using "doxygen -u"
[ 11%] Built target doc
make: *** [all] Error 2

I admit to be fully out of my depth here.  I have looked up the errors and have seen some threads suggesting not building doxygen in osx.  Not sure that is helpful.  I have no idea how I would make that happen or correct this issue.
FWIW: doxygen is installed and it says its up to date.
 Warning: doxygen 1.12.0 is already installed and up-to-date.

Can anyone offer me some advice on how I might get Gazebo to install on my mini?
thanks in advance.
steve
